# Linear algorithm for finding the celebrity group, not single celebrity

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have N people and there **might be** a group of celebrities inside.

Every person knows every celebrity and every celebrity knows only every other celebrity.

If you are given the function of `know x y` which `returns true or false`, identify the group of celebrities.

This problem is to **identify a group of celebrities**, and it is **not identifying the only celebrity** among the people, such as http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-celebrity-problem/.

---

Using brute force is easy. I can construct all possible sub-sequences of N people and filter them with the condition (everyone knows every celebrity and every celebrity knows only other celebrity).

Also I know there must be only one celebrity group or none.

Proof:

Suppose we have two celebrity groups, C1 and C2. Because everyone knows ci from C1, so every cj from C2 also knows ci; symmetrically, every ci knows cj; So C1 and C2 actually belongs to one group. So we have at most one celebrity group or none.

Any ideas on possible **linear algorithm**?

There might be a group of celebrity and there might be none.

Comment: A single celebrity knows every other celebrity? As in, ANY single celebrity knows EVERY other celebrity?

Comment: Can a non-celebrity know any number of other non-celebrities as well, or not?

Comment: Does every person know only ever celebrity or can two non-celebrities know each other?

Comment: @Dukeling it doesn't say and doesn't matter

Comment: @isick yes, two non-celebrities may know each other, but doesn't matter

Comment: Certainly does matter. Consider every person ONLY knows every celebrity. Then you just iterate over the group once seeing if the first person knows them and you're done.

Comment: @isick ok, what I meant is that between non-celebrities the condition is loose. They may know each other or not. If every person knows only every celebrity, then it is a special case. Basically, if a problem statement does not define some condition strictly, then it means you should not assume anything about that condition. Like sorting an array, if it does not say array is distinct, you cant assume it is distinct

Comment: The most challenging case is if everyone knows everyone, since this requires N*(N-1) calls to `know` to verify that everyone is a celebrity.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be the intersection of everyone's set of persons they know?

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca, would that be linear time though? I think it would be `O(N^2)` since you would have to generate a list of length `N` per each of the `N` people? But it's a good approach as I don't see a linear algorithm for as @Daniel points out.

Comment: @ijkilchenko I misread and thought you have the connection info upfront... As is I'm thinking it's N^3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in O(N) (but see 2nd edit below). Here's one algorithm.

Enumerate all N people from 0 to N-1.

```
int find_a_celebrity()
{
    int C = 0; // C is a potential celebrity
    for( int i=0 ; i<N ; ++i )
      if( !know(i,C) ) // C is not a celebrity nor are all j<i, but i might be.
        C = i; 
    for( int i=0 ; i<N ; ++i ) // Loop a second time to check everyone knows C.
      if( !know(i,C) ) return -1;
    return C;
}
int C = find_a_celebrity();
```

If `C==-1` then there are no celebrities. Otherwise the set `{ y | know(C,y) }` is the set of all celebrities. All together, this took at most 3 iterations through all N people, so this is discovered in time `O(N)`.

Edit:

```
// Output the set of celebrities
if( C == -1 ) std::cout << "There are no celebrities.";
else for( int i=0 ; i<N ; ++i ) if( know(C,i) ) std::cout << i << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Edit 2:

There are two interpretations to this problem:

1. The definition of a celebrity is that they are known by everyone. By a constraint of the problem, all celebrities only know other celebrities.
2. The definition of a celebrity is that they are known by everyone, and celebrities only know other celebrities.

The above algorithm solves this for case #1. This works for case #2 as well, as long as we can assume that *there exists at least one celebrity*. Otherwise we will have to verify at the end that the list of potential celebrities only know each other, which requires `O(N*M)` time where M is the number of potential celebrities.

Comment: @JacksonTale Done. Hope that helps.

Comment: All non-celebrities don't necessarily know each other, so I don't think this will work (you start off with C = a non-celeb A, non-celeb B doesn't know A, thus you assign C to B, then return -1 because everyone doesn't know B).

Comment: what @Dukeling says is true. We can't assume all non-celebrities know each other.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes that's correct, all non-celebs may not know each other, and that is not assumed. Your example is not complete - yes C=B, but it still checks the remainder of the list for other potential celebs. If it finds one, then it assigns it to C. If not, there there are no celebs and -1 is the correct return value.

Comment: suppose we have 3 persons: 0, 1, and 2. 1 and 2 know 0, so from your first loop, C = 0. Also second loop will give C = 0. Suppose 0 knows 1 but 2 doesn't know 1, then your 3rd loop will give 1 as celebrity as well, but it is not true because 2 doesn't know 1.

Comment: @JacksonTale In your example, since everyone knows 0, by definition 0 is a celebrity. By constraint, 0 only knows other celebrities, so 0 cannot know 1 since 1 is not a celebrity.

Comment: @JacksonTale What I'm saying is that your example is not a valid possibility given the constraints of the problem. I guess this brings up a question worth clarifying: What is the definition of a celebrity? I am assuming that someone is a celebrity if and only if they are known by everyone. It is then a constraint of the problem that each celebrity only knows other celebrities. The alternative definition which would require both conditions as part of the definition doesn't make much sense, in my opinion, since if applied to your example there are no celebrities, even though everyone knows 0.

Comment: Your algorithm will find at most one celebrity (I doubt it will even get that far, but suppose it does). If C is a celebrity your claim that the set of all celebrities is "y | know(C,y)" is false because that is true for ALL people. Everyone knows every celebrity.

Comment: @isick No. Say A and B are not celebrities, but A knows B. Then `{y | know(A,y) }` is not the set of celebrities, because it includes B. So it is not true for "ALL people", contrary to your claim.

Comment: I see, I neglected the ordering of your parameters so your last claim is true that given C you can find all celebs. However, the assumption that you'll find the celebrity in two for loops is unproven and I think not true. Assume I have a list size N=100 with 10 celebrities all listed at the end (90-99). The first 3 people (0-2) all know eachother (a little triangle) and the next 3 people (3-5) all know eachother (another little triangle), and every other person ONLY knows celebrities. Your algorithm will return no celebrities because the first loop breaks at 3 and the second loop breaks at 0.

Comment: @isick The first loop never breaks; it *always* goes through all `N` values. So in your example, when the first loop ends, C=90. (When i=90, `know(90,j)` is false for any j<90 since 90 is a celebrity and j is not.) Since C=90 is a celebrity, it goes through then 2nd loop, and then `find_a_celebrity()` returns 90. Finally, it is required by the problem that each celebrity only knows other celebrities, so the output would be "90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99" since these are the only values `y` for which `know(90,y)` is true.

Comment: @Matt Ah, my mistake. This is clear reason why I shouldn't try solving algorithms late at night. I retract my former criticism - thanks for clarifying! You have my vote!

Comment: The condition for a celebrity group is stated clearly: **Every person knows every celebrity and every celebrity knows only every other celebrity.** Note there is an **and** inside. So a celebrity group must meet both conditions. It is like the statement: `a good day should not have rains and it should have sun`. So a day that does not have rains and does not have sun either is NOT a good day. If a day does not have rains, you can't assume it must have sun, right? In your solution, you are replying on only the first condition `everyone knows a celebrity` sololy.

Comment: Further to my comment above, under **Every person knows every celebrity and every celebrity knows only every other celebrity**, it means if A is known by everyone, but A knows someone that is not known by everyone, then A is not celebrity.

Comment: @JacksonTale Fair enough - that's certainly a self-consistent interpretation of the problem, I just don't think it makes as much sense as mine, but that's just an opinion. To demonstrate using your example in which "A is known by everyone, but A knows someone that is not known by everyone" then there can not be **any** celebrities, since if there were, they would have to know A, which is a contradiction since no celebrity can know a non-celebrity.

Comment: I think I forgot to state that `there is a group of celebrity or none`. However, again, you can't conclude `no celebrities` just from `"A is known by everyone, but A knows someone that is not known by everyone"`. The conclusion sololy from this statement is only `A is not celebrity`

Comment: @JacksonTale I disagree. If "A is known by everyone, but A knows someone that is not known by everyone" then A is not a celebrity, right? This makes **everyone** a non-celebrity, since no celebrity can know A. In any case, I've modified my answer above to accommodate this interpretation.

Comment: ahh, ok, you are right. If everyone knows A and A is a non-celebrity, then everyone is non-celebrity, because everyone knows the known non-celebrity A. true

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, especially when there must be a celebrity group and it is linear

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: I didn't read the problem statement carefully enough.  You don't have a list of all edges and we're assuming we can't generate it in linear time.*

The key here is that every person knows every celebrity.  Formulate this problem as a directed adjacency graph with V vertexes (celebrities) and E edges (relationships) connecting them.

Iterate through the list E to count how many times each person is known.  Celebrities are known V-1 times; everyone else is a non-celebrity.  Running time should be O(E).

Comment: I thought about a graph too, but constructing the graph would be expensive (there are a quadratic number of relationships already).

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only need the list of celebrities and the list of relationships; you don't need an actual matrix or 2D array to implement a graph.

Comment: Yeah but you don't have a list of relationships you only have a function to determine a relationship given two people.

Comment: Oh, that's right... I've seen this problem before, let me see if I can remember the trick behind solving it in linear time.

Comment: @Daniel contructing such a graph from `function know` will have O(n^2)

Comment: You could conjecture that it can't be done in linear time given that you don't know if any one person is a celebrity until you've determined that everyone knows them. And since the "knows" function can only compare one person to another, it must be run N times to determine one person's celebrity status... There must be a proof by contradiction in there somewhere.

Comment: I agree.  Consider the worst case: everyone knows everyone.  You won't have a complete list of celebrities until you've checked all N*(N-1) relationships.

Comment: @Daniel Not so. If everyone knows everyone, you can start with 1 person called C. Check that everyone knows C. Then C is a celebrity. By definition, everyone else that C knows is also a celebrity, and in fact that is all the celebrities, and you are done in O(N). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Being a celebrity is the state of being known without knowing. Being normal is the state of knowing without being known. Therefore comparing each person to the person next to them would look something like:

```
foreach person in persons
{
  knows = know(person, next_person)
  isknown = know(next_person, person)

  if knows and !isknown then normal
  if !knows and isknown then celeb
  if !knows and !isknown then normal
  if knows and isknown then friends.add(person)

  foreach friend in friends
  {
      alsoknows = know(person, friend)
      if !alsoknows then normal; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Construct a sublist of friends is an interesting approach. I think your criteria is a little off in that you can't say for certain that person is a celebrity just because another person knows them; everyone must know them. But the idea of creating a sublist is still interesting. However, you'll have to nest loops over the "friends" list to be certain your final list is exhaustive and exclusive. And in cases where everyone knows the next_person your friends list will be a clone of the starting "persons" list which means it's still O(N^2)

Comment: Yes my solution is flawed. I only left it up because I thought it might contribute some notions. My wife told me to stop trying to solve this :)

Comment: @isick I should add that you can definitely say that someone is a celebrity because another person knows them AND they don't know that person.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where all N*(N-1) possible evaluations of knows(x,y) are true. In this case, all N people are celebrities. Next, consider the case where all but one of the N*(N-1) evaluations of knows(x,y) are true. According to [this comment by the asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983260/linear-algorithm-for-finding-the-celebrity-group-not-single-celebrity#comment31544284_20984105), I expect that we should interpret this scenario as having zero celebrities. In order to distinguish these two situations, you need to evaluate all possible N*(N-1) pairs.

Answer (score -1):

Let `candidates` be a list of all `n` people. Contstruct a cycle of all people:

`1 -> 2 -> ... -> n -> 1`.

Now, check one by one `knows k,k+1`. If true than `k = k+1` and continue. If `knows k,k+1 == False`, **then  `k+1` is not a celebrity** so remove him from `candidates` and check `k,k+2` instead.

We finish when we haven't removed anyone in last `size(candidates)` turns.

**Proof:**

If there is a celebrity in the list then:

1. he will never be removed
2. once we reach him we go further to the last celebrity
3. algorithm will remove all non-celebrities 'after the last one' till we get another celebrity and then we get back to 2.

Finally we will get a cycle of celebrities.

If there is no celebrity in the list, then follow @Matt's answer.

Comment: it is not correct. suppose 0 doesn't know 1 or 2, and 1 doesn't know 0 either. in your algorithm, 0 will be the only one left, but it is not the correct answer

Comment: If 0 doesn't know 1 then 1 is not a celebrity and we may remove him - information he provides is redundant in the context of my algorithm. Now, if 0 stays in the cycle and there is at least 1 celebrity then at some point 0 will be removed. If there are no celebrities in the cycle then contradiction with **"there is a group of celebrities inside"** (I'm assuming it's size is positive).

Comment: Ps. If we include possibility that there is no celebrities at all then it is impossible to solve the problem. For each group of people where there is a celebrity we can construct another group with **exactly the same relation `knows`** without celebrities. So we can't distinguish those two cases.

Comment: +1 Nice one. Like my answer, this works if we know there exists at least 1 celebrity. Otherwise, this produces only a list of potential celebrities, which then requires O(N*M) time to verify, where M is the size of the resulting list.

Comment: Actually if there is no celebrities and a clique of posers (non celebrities knowing only each other) we won't be able to verify.

Comment: @ŁukaszKidzińki Why's that? For each member `c` of the resulting list, you simply verify that `know(x,c)` for all `x`, and that `know(c,x)` is true exactly when `x` is also in the list. If these conditions are satisfied, then you have your celebrity list. Otherwise, there are no celebrities.

Comment: @Matt Take a group of 3 people with no celebrities. 2 people knowing only each other and the 3rd person who knows them. It is equivalent to the case of 2 celebrities and 1 person who knows them. They are equivalent in terms of `knows` relation but results should be different.

Comment: @ŁukaszKidzińki In that example, the two people who know only each other is the entire list of celebrities. What's the problem?

Comment: It is not the list of celebrities because we assumed there are no celebrities. We just provided a graph of relations of people who happen to know each other (but are not celebrities).

Comment: It's the graph that determines who the celebrities are - not some magical coloring applied to the nodes. In your example, everyone knows those two people who only know each other. By **definition** those are the celebrities. It is not a quality that is externally bestowed upon them which is independent of the graph structure.

Comment: If we define the problem like this, then I totally agree :)

Comment: How else would you determine whether or not they are a celebrity? Whether or not they look like Tom Cruise? ;)

Comment: Well, even with magical coloring approach, if we just add the assumption that there is at least one celebrity then everything works nicely. So it is not totally irrelevant.

Comment: That's because the assumption that there is at least one celebrity places a specific requirement on the graph structure. It's all about graph structure, nothing more (not how the nodes are colored, etc.)

Comment: Or it's all about coloring and the graph follows. Unimportant though :)

Comment: It is important to make these distinctions if this kind of confusion is going to lead you to conclude that this is "unsolvable" under certain conditions as is currently stated in your answer.

Comment: Yes, it is important to make these distinctions - it should be clarified by the author. I don't see anything wrong in both interpretations. My conclusion was too strong though.